# Drupal 6: how to display node with its local tasks tabs in menu item

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, menu

In my case each user has a gallery. Gallery is a node. I'd like to hide default "Create content" menu and add custom menu link that links to user gallery.

```
function custom_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['galleries/editgallery'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit gallery',
  'description' => 'edit gallery',
    'page callback' => 'custom_edit_gallery',
    'access callback' => 'custom_access_editgallery',
  );
  return $items;
}

function custom_edit_gallery (){
  global $user;
  $node = node_load ($user->gallerynid);
  return node_page_view ($node);
}
```

But it doesn't show local tasks tabs(like "Edit" tab).

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add them yourself.

- With normal theming, you could create a custom template file or overwrite a theme function etc to add the tabs you want.
- You could also do this within `hook_menu`, by using `MENU_LOCAL_TASK` and `MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK`, see the [api](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu/6).

Comment: I still believe it's can be done somehow without local task dublication. At least I can use

    menu_set_active_item ('node/37');
    return menu_execute_active_handler();

but this ruin my menu trails.